# Devexpress TileView Datasource

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a Devexpress winforms `GridView` that I would like to convert to a `TileView`. Here is my current `GridView` at runtime:

[image]

This GridView is populated using a List datasource and it works fine. I convert the `GridView` to a `TileView` using the Designer:

[image]

After successfully converting the GridView, I tried to run the App, It shows the right number of records, but it is blank:

[image]

Am I missing anything? Here is a code to populate the grids:

```
using (var sovDB = new MyEntities())
   {
      gridControl1.BeginUpdate();
      tileView1.Columns.Clear();
      gridControl1.DataSource = null;
      var query = (from b in sovDB.Palletes
                      join ipc in sovDB.IPCDisplays on b.DisplayNo equals ipc.DisplayNo
                             orderby b.PalleteID
                             select new
                             {
                                 PalletNo = b.PalleteNumber,
                                 Packs = b.CurrentPackCount,
                                 Mass = b.CurrentPackWeight + " Kg"

                 }).ToList();
          gridControl1.DataSource = query;
          gridControl1.EndUpdate();

     }
```

Comment: I guess no one knows the answer to this question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create `TileViewItemElement` objects that will correspond to columns of DataSource using the `TileViewItemElement.Column` property like this :

```
tileView1.TileTemplate.Add(new TileViewItemElement { Column = tileView1.Columns["PalletNo"], TextAlignment = TileItemContentAlignment.TopCenter });
tileView1.TileTemplate.Add(new TileViewItemElement { Column = tileView1.Columns["Packs"], ImageAlignment = TileItemContentAlignment.TopLeft });
tileView1.TileTemplate.Add(new TileViewItemElement { Column = tileView1.Columns["Mass"], ImageAlignment = TileItemContentAlignment.BottomRight });
```

You can also configure the `TileTemplate` by Design Mode like this :

[Basic configuration of the TileTemplate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpyv9ImbTjQ)

Comment: must i do this before i bind my list array to the gridControl?

Comment: After binding DataSource.

Comment: wow dude!!!, i wish i could give you a bounty right now....I struggled with this the whole day

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :)

Comment: I started a bounty but i have to wait for 24 hours to award it to you.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much :)

Comment: glad to hear that, Thank you again :)